# Indexing a vector within a bigger one in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to find the index position of the smaller vector inside a bigger one.

I've already solved this problem using `strfind` and `bind2dec`, 
but I don't want to use `strfind`, I don't want to convert to string or to deciamls at all.

Given the **longer vector**

```
a=[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1];
```

I want to find the index of the **smaller vector** b inside a

```
b=[1,1,1,0,0,0];
```

I would expect to find as **result**:

```
result=[15,16,17,18,19,20];
```

Thank you

Comment: What is your solution with `strfind`? Do you know you can just use `strfind(a,b)` without converting to strings (but that's undocumented)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution with `for` loops:

```matlab
a=[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1];
b=[1,1,1,0,0,0];
c = [];
b_len = length(b)
maxind0 = length(a) - b_len + 1 %no need to search higher indexes 

for i=1:maxind0
  found = 0;
  for j=1:b_len
    if a(i+j-1) == b(j)
      found = found + 1;
    else
      break;
    end
  end

  if found == b_len  % if sequence is found fill c with indexes
    for j=1:b_len
      c(j)= i+j-1;
    end

    break
  end
end

c %display c
```

Comment: what about if new_a=a' ? (i transpose a).
Also b is transposable

Comment: if it's still vector you could replace `size(v,2)` with `length(v)`

Answer (score 7):

Here is as solution using 1D convolution. It may find multiple matches so `start` holds beginning indices of sub-vectors:

```
f = flip(b);

idx = conv(a,f,'same')==sum(b) & conv(~a,~f,'same')==sum(~b);

start = find(idx)-ceil(length(b)/2)+1;

result = start(1):start(1)+length(b)-1;
```

Answer (score 3):

Does it need to be computationally efficient?

A not very efficient but short solution would be this:

```
a=[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1];;
b=[1,1,1,0,0,0];
where = find(arrayfun(@(n) all(a(n+1:n+length(b))==b),0:length(a)-length(b)));
```

... gives you 15. Your `result` would be the vector `where:where+length(b)-1`.

**edit**: I tried it and I stand corrected. Here is a version with loops:

```
function where = find_sequence(a,b)

na = 0;
where = [];
while na < length(a)-length(b)
    c = false;
    for nb = 1:length(b)
        if a(na+nb)~=b(nb)
            na = na + 1;  % + nb
            c = true;                        
            break
        end

    end
    if ~c
        where = [where,na+1];
        na = na + 1;
    end   
end
```

Despite its loops and their bad reputation in Matlab, it's a lot faster:

```
a = round(rand(1e6,1));
b = round(rand(10,1));

tic;where1 = find(arrayfun(@(n) all(a(n+1:n+length(b))==b),0:length(a)-length(b)));toc;
tic;where2 = find_sequence(a,b);toc;


>> test_find_sequence
Elapsed time is 4.419223 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.042969 seconds.
```

Comment: Yes, efficency is important. Also I am asking because strfind and bin2dec require to much memory to work

Comment: Try this one and see how it fares for you.It is inefficient for longer vectors `b` since it will always compare the whole vector while one could stop as soon as there is one mismatch. To fix this, one would have to use loops which are not the most efficient in Matlab either. My gut feeling is that as long as `b` is very short compared to `a` it should do okay.

Comment: Okay, after testing I found that using the loops is considerably faster. Just saw now after posting my update that barbsan has already suggested a very similar version before I did.

Answer (score 2):

A neater method using `for` would look like this, there is no need for an inner checking loop as we can vectorize that with `all`...

```
a = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1];
b = [1,1,1,0,0,0];

idx = NaN( size(b) ); % Output NaNs if not found
nb = numel( b );      % Store this for re-use

for ii = 1:numel(a)-nb+1
    if all( a(ii:ii+nb-1) == b )
        % If matched, update the index and exit the loop
        idx = ii:ii+nb-1;
        break
    end
end
```

Output:

```
idx = [15,16,17,18,19,20]
```

Note, I find this a bit easier to read that some of the nested solutions, but it's not necessarily faster, since the comparison is done on all elements in `b` each time.